# Axios MSAL Request Interceptor Attach Token

Tags: reactjs, azure-ad-msal

I am using Axios to send requests and msal for authentication. Instead of attaching the access token to each request, I am using Axios interceptors to handle it globally. Since this is not part of a react component, I won't be able to use the msal hooks. Hence, I am exporting the `PublicClientApplication` instance passed into the `MsalProvider`.

Firstly, I am not sure if this is the best approach or if there is a better option. Secondly, doing it like this, I cannot redirect in case of a required interaction. I commented out the lines in the code below. [Microsoft mentions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-acquire-token?tabs=react):

> Alternatively, if you need to acquire a token outside of a React
> component you can call acquireTokenSilent but shouldn't fall back to
> interaction if it fails. All interactions should take place underneath
> the MsalProvider component in your component tree.

So now I am missing behaviour if I simply remove those lines. What are some other way of doing it then?

```
import { InteractionRequiredAuthError } from '@azure/msal-browser'
import axios from 'axios'
import { azureAdInstance } from '../index'

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://myapi.com",
})

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(async (request) => {
    const instance = azureAdInstance
    const accounts = azureAdInstance.getAllAccounts()

    const accessTokenRequest = {
        scopes: ["scope1"],
        account: accounts[0],
    }

    // Silently acquires an access token which is then attached to a request
    try {
        const { accessToken } = await instance.acquireTokenSilent(
            accessTokenRequest
        )
        if (accessToken) request.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`
    } catch (error) {
        // Should not be used according to MS documentation
        // if (error instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
        //    instance.acquireTokenRedirect(accessTokenRequest)
        // }
        console.log(error)
    }

    return request
})

export default axiosInstance
```

Comment: Did you find some way around this? Or did the error scenario never happen?

Comment: It hasn't happened but I am not really happy with this solution either. @Rex

Comment: I had a similar issue, and this article helped me: https://dev.to/arianhamdi/react-hooks-in-axios-interceptors-3e1h